# SDMTools: how to calculate total edge of a patch excluding landscape boundary?

Tags: r, sdmtools

I'm using Classtat (SDMtools package) to calculate the total edge\edge density of a patch type (class) i in a restricted area (buffer) of a landscape . The problem is when I do that the buffer boundary is considered an edge. There is a way to exclude the boundary edge using R?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem a while back and we wrote a correction for this. If you are familiar with coding, feel free to take a look here: [https://github.com/dbahrdt/SDMTools/tree/ignore_invalid](https://github.com/dbahrdt/SDMTools/commit/eb34f257ddd479765a7316e1e0760d96e1fb013f#diff-fd68f3c23dd55e9afc0ea1426c5809cd)

Otherwise, just install the correction via:

```
install_github('dbahrdt/SDMTools@ignore_invalid')
```

This should do exactly what you asked for, exclude the buffer-border from calculation of edge-density.